# How to find an object in an array of objects if some array elements are undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects with the following format:

```
obj = { ref: 8, id: "obj-8" }
```

and a function which uses jQuery's *grep* method to return an item from that array, by searching for the object *ref* property:

```
function returnObj(arr,r){
    return $.grep(arr, function(elem,index){ return elem.ref == r; })[0];
}
```

If I use this function on an array that has undefined elements in it (they were previously deleted using the *delete* operator), I get the following error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined*, which I assume is thrown when an undefined element is encountered.

How can I modify the function so it doesn't break?

Comment: `return elem && elem.ref == r;`

Comment: also, why use `$.grep` when it essentially does the same thing as `Array.filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if the current item is `undefined`, or simply "falsey" if you expect specifc objects, and return `false` if so.

```
function returnObj(arr,r){
    return $.grep(arr, function(elem,index){ 
                           return elem ? elem.ref == r : false;
                       })[0];
}
```

---

Here's another option. Since you're using `delete` to remove the items, you can use the native `.filter` method, which skips over non-existent array members.

```
function returnObj(arr,r){
    return arr.filter(function(elem){ elem.ref == r})[0];
}
```

Comment: How do I do that exactly? I'm not exactly sure I understand the code line "return elem.ref == r;" (the function was written by someone else) so I'm finding it difficult to modify it.

Comment: @AndreiOniga: That's a *conditional operator*. Basically it says *"if `elem` evaluates to a `true` value, return the result of `elem.ref == r` otherwise return `false`"*

Comment: @AndreiOniga: If you're saying you don't understand the way it was originally written, basically `$.grep` evaluates the returned value as `true` or `false` evaluations. If a "truthy" value is returned, it adds the current `item` to the new Array it is building. If "falsey" it doesn't. Then your function is simply returning the first item in the resulting Array.

Comment: @AndreiOniga: One more thing. You should be aware that `delete` leaves a hole in the Array. It doesn't re-index the Array, resulting in a shorter Array. If you want the Array to be reindexed when something is removed, then use `.splice()`. `arr.splice(idx, 1)` This will remove `1` item located at the given `idx`, and will resolve your issue with `undefined` items.

Comment: Well, it seems that I understood the delete op. and splice() method the other way around, that's the only reason why. Now that you've mentioned it, I swapped them. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

just check that it's not `undefined`:

```
function returnObj(arr,r){
    return $.grep(arr, function(elem,index){
        return elem ? elem.ref == r : false; 
    })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could simply add a test for undefined:

```
return $.grep(arr, function(elem,index){ return elem != undefined && elem.ref == r; })[0];
```

But I'm not sure why you're using `$.grep`. You could use the existing `Array.filter` to achieve the same result:

```
function returnObj(arr,r){
    return arr.filter(function(ele,index){return ele && ele.ref == r;})[0];
}
```